# High School Pentagon Vectorial Geometry question

Tags: geometry, vectors

I’ve stumbled upon this problem which I thought was simple, but as I was trying to solve it I got stuck.

“The convex pentagon ABCDE is considered with the property that AB is parallel to CE, BC is parallel to DA, CD is parallel to EB, and DE is parallel to AC. Show that EA is parallel to BD”

I’ve tried adding and subtracting some vectors, finding angles, finding similarities between triangles, but in the end I didn’t reach anything. I’d appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction, thank you very much!

[image: Sketch]

Comment: Basic angle chasing works, esp with so many parallel lines. If you're stuck, please add a diagram indicating what angles you're looking at.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you, I have tried chasing the angles but I get stuck because there are too many, and often I reach the starting point. I have updated my post with a simple sketch I made.

Comment: Can you label the 3 angles at $\angle AEB$ and the 2 angles at $\angle ABD$ and chase them individually around the pentagon , to see if we can align them with another set of parallel lines?

Comment: @CalvinLin I don’t really understand, which 3 angles at AEB and 2 angles at ABD?

Comment: For each of the angles like $\angle ACE$, chase them around the pentagon and label them. EG $ \angle ACE = \angle CED = \angle BAC$. $\quad$ Then, show that $ \angle AEB + \angle ABD = \ldots = 180^\circ$ by following them all over. $\quad$ As a heads up, you can't chase $ \angle DAE, \angle AEB$ because they don't have parallel lines for you to work with, but what can we do with them combined?

Answer (score 1):

Given, $AB||CE$ 
$\implies (\vec{B}-\vec{A})\times(\vec{E}-\vec{C}) = 0$ 
$\implies (\vec{A}\times\vec{C})-(\vec{A}\times\vec{E})-(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})+(\vec{B}\times\vec{E})=0$

Likewise, the other three conditions give,
$(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})-(\vec{A}\times\vec{C})+(\vec{B}\times\vec{D})-(\vec{C}\times\vec{D})=0$
$-(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})+(\vec{B}\times\vec{D})-(\vec{C}\times\vec{E})+(\vec{D}\times\vec{E})=0$
$-(\vec{A}\times\vec{D})+(\vec{A}\times\vec{E})+(\vec{C}\times\vec{D})-(\vec{C}\times\vec{E})=0$
By adding and subtracting these equations, we obtain:
$(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})-(\vec{A}\times\vec{D})+(\vec{B}\times\vec{E})-(\vec{D}\times\vec{E})=0$,
which is equivalent to
$(\vec{A}-\vec{E})\times(\vec{B}-\vec{D})=0$
i.e, $EA||BD$.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I am in 9th grade and have only learned simple vectors operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication with a constant). Is there a simpler solution which I may understand?

Comment: @Andrew Please don't ask for spoon feeding with solutions delivered on a sliver plate. Follow the existing hints in the other comments. Do you know about the sum of angles in an arbitrary triangle? Stuff that is 2500 years old.